# How to convert swig object of type 'int *' to ctypes int*

Tags: python, c++

I was using Python to process some data (int array). It is very slow. So I put the processing function in a c++ DLL and talk with it through ctypes. The data are loaded from swig-wrapped modules (c++). I browsed almost everywhere but found nothing to convert swig object of type 'int *' pointer to ctypes int pointer. How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: In C and C++, a pointer is always a number. To be exact, it's a number of type intptr_t, a platform-dependent type alias aliased to an integer type large enough to hold the memory address. So...why not just pass it directly? In either case, it's a number.

Comment: Got wrong data address if pass it directly. Anywhere except the beginning of data array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no solution to do that after a few attempts. A simple way to fix this problem is wrapping the c++ code with SWIG, so can pass it to other SWIG-wrapped modules.