# Passing arguments to C-function wrapped with SWIG for Python

Tags: python, c

I want to use a proprietary library given by:

```
library.dll
library.lib
header1.h
header2.h
```

Beside typedef structs the *.h-files contain dozens of very large:

```
EXIMPORT functionName
( int hello,
  int *alpha,
  double *bravo,  
  double **charlie,
  specialType **delta,
  ...
  superType *echo,
  int (*whatever)(int*,double*,char*,int,double,char),
  int (*something)(arbitrary *)
);
```

So I created this "library.i"-file...

```
%module "library"
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "folder/header1.h"
#include "folder/header2.h"
%}
/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "folder/header1.h"
%include "folder/header2.h"
```

...wrapping and compiling it with...

```
swig -python -o library_wrap.cpp library.i
g++ -c -Wall library_wrap.cpp -I C:\Python27\include
g++ -Wall -shared library_wrap.o -o _library.pyd -L C:\Python27\libs\ -lpython27 -L D:\swigwin-3.0.10\folder\ -llibrary
```

...which creates "library.py" and "_library.pyd". Then in Python...

```
import library
library.functionName()
```

...returns to...

```
TypeError: functionName() takes exactly 42 arguments (0 given)
```

Now, how do I pass and return all arguments? So far I found this:

[Passing reference from Python to c++ function wrapped with swig for return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331791/passing-reference-from-python-to-c-function-wrapped-with-swig-for-return-value)

[How to convert swig object of type 'int *' to ctypes int*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471470/how-to-convert-swig-object-of-type-int-to-ctypes-int)

Do I really have to write all these typemaps manually? This is unacceptable due to the large count and size of functions... isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Is this question about C or C++?  Please pick one and delete the other tag.